# Does level shifter have a maximum speed?

Tags: microcontroller, nodemcu, ws2811

Of course it does, but what's it likely to BE?

I have a string of WS2811 LEDs which accept a 5V logic signal. I am running them from a LoLin board, whose GPIO ports output 3.3V logic.

I've put a Sparkfun logic level converter in between, but it doesn't seem to work.

The peak output voltage has gone up to a little over 3.3V, but the rise time is slower, so I think the average "high" is about the same.
Here's my input (output from the MCU):

[image: Output from the MCU]

Here's my output (from the level shifter):

[image: output from the level shifter]

So, is my assertion correct that there's a rise time associated with the device and a 800kHz waveform is basically just too fast?

....or am I just not using it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see a part number for your level shifter but I assume it was the "SparkFun Logic Level Converter - Bi-Directional"
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009

In the schematic for that design we see that they are using the BSS138 transistor and 10K pull-up resistors.  The datasheet for the BSS138 is here.
https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BSS138-D.PDF

As you can see in the datasheet there is 13pF of input capacitance and 27pF of output capacitance.  That capacitance varies with applied voltage so its a bit hard to say what the exact timing is going to be, but **transition times on the order of a few hundred nano-seconds would not be unreasonable**.

The rise time is directly proportional to the FET capacitance and the pull-up resistor value.  So if you want to make it faster, replace the 10K pull-ups with 1K pull-ups.

Comment: It's the other type. It's got a FET on one channel and a resistor bridge on the other, but the schematic for the bidirectional side is the same as you included. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is the limitation of FET level shifters. It is not the correct tool for the task you need to do.

Few meters of wire would have enough capacitance to slow down the rising edges, and the sharpness is also defined by the resistance value pulling the voltage up.

They are good for only low speed applications, and they are the right tool for bi-directional open-collector communications like I2C buses.

You simply need a push-pull logic level buffer, that can take in a 3.3V CMOS level signal, and output a 5V CMOS level signal.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. A good and fast level shifter will solve your issue. But I found this:
[image: CHEATING AT 5V WS2812 CONTROL TO USE 3.3V DATA]

It uses a diode to provide the first LED with a lower supply voltage (4.3v) and uses the data output of this LED (with 4.3v logic) to feed the next ones. Surely this makes the first LED with lower light, so you can remove it from the strip and just use it as a level shifter.
More info can be found here:

[CHEATING AT 5V WS2812 CONTROL TO USE 3.3V DATA](https://hackaday.com/2017/01/20/cheating-at-5v-ws2812-control-to-use-a-3-3v-data-line/)

Comment: It may work in some cases but in general it is not a good solution as it will not always work. The chip is specified to operate properly with 4.5 to 5.5 volts, and the 4.3V provided would not be within operating range any more. And to see 3.3 logic levels properly, the supply voltage would have to be below 3.3/0.7= 4.71V. So if anyone wants to use this circuit, be aware that it may not work.